# Realm Strict mode violation, freezes app when loading

Tags: java, android, realm

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

**Configuring realm makes my app load slower, looks like the app is freezing, how can I overcome this issue ?**

```
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=36 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=65567 violation=2

D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=35 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=65567 violation=2

D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=35 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=65567 violation=2
```

Comment: When creating the first instance of Realm, it will take some time to verify the schemas. There is a similar issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2299 . What you can work around is creating the first instance in the background thread, keep it open until your Realm instance in UI thread created. But it would be strange if the `RealmConfiguration` slows down anything, since the two lines of code you posted won't do anything takes time.

Comment: I add configuration codes to application class, that is why it looks like it is freezing. If i don't add them there I get an exception saying, realm is not configured.

Comment: @Mike could you provide a bit more code from your application class?

Comment: Hey, have you found any solution for that ? I am facing with the similar issue but do not know how to solve. Thanks!